# How to move autocompleted closing tag in Visual Studio

Tags: html, visual-studio, autocomplete

I want to make Visual Studio move the autocompleted closing tag a word (or more) to the right. For example, given the following HTML:

```
<p>I need to emphasize some text.</p>
```

If I type `<em>` before the word "emphasize", Visual Studio autocompletes like so:

```
<p>I need to <em></em>emphasize some text.</p>
```

Then I need to move the closing `</em>` to get what I want:

```
<p>I need to <em>emphasize</em> some text.</p>
```

Is there a way to make Visual Studio do that last step automatically?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your question got me thinking how cool it would be if this functionality existed. Luckily, it was pretty simple to implement as a macro in VS. Below is the code for the macro. You can easily bind this to CTRL+ALT+Right using the customization tool in VS.

(**Note**: I just threw this together quickly being that it's Friday evening)

```
Sub MoveClosingTag()
    Dim ts As EnvDTE.TextSelection = CType(DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection(), EnvDTE.TextSelection)
    Dim start As EditPoint = ts.ActivePoint.CreateEditPoint()
    Dim tag As String

    ts.WordRight(True)
    If ts.Text = "</" Then
        Do Until ts.ActivePoint.AtEndOfLine
            ts.CharRight(True)
            If ts.Text.EndsWith(">") Then Exit Do
        Loop
        tag = ts.Text
        If tag.EndsWith(">") Then
            ts.Delete()
            ts.WordRight(False)
            ts.Insert(tag, EnvDTE.vsInsertFlags.vsInsertFlagsCollapseToStart)
        Else
            ts.MoveToPoint(start)
        End If
    Else
        ts.MoveToPoint(start)
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't think this is possible. However, you can configure which HTML tags will be closed automatically:

Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> HTML -> Format -> "Tag Specific Options" button -> Client HTML Tags -> em -> Closing Tag -> No Closing Tag

Please also consider that automatically moving the closing tagis not trivial (what should be the Word boundary?) and it would cover only a very special use case (only one Word should be e.g. highlighted).

Comment: It would be nice if there was HTML refactoring type function so you could select what you want inside the tags and then choose 'wrap with' the desired tag.

Comment: I'd actually prefer something like a CTRL+right arrow that would move the closing tag one word to the right. That way you could do it as many times as needed...

Comment: @Hugh: Yea, that would be cool too. I actually tried that to see if it would work.

Answer (score 2):

Props to @w4g3n3r for doing the hard work. I've modified the macro a bit to play nicer with spaces.

Note: I find that `CTRL+.` works nicely as a shortcut key for this; your right ring finger's already on the `.` key in the use case I originally described.

```
Sub MoveClosingTag()
    Dim ts As EnvDTE.TextSelection = CType(DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection(), EnvDTE.TextSelection)
    Dim start As EditPoint = ts.ActivePoint.CreateEditPoint()
    Dim tag As String

    ts.WordRight(True)
    If ts.Text = "</" Then
        Do Until ts.ActivePoint.AtEndOfLine
            ts.CharRight(True)
            If ts.Text.EndsWith(">") Then Exit Do
        Loop
        tag = ts.Text
        If tag.EndsWith(">") Then
            ts.Delete()
            Dim pos As Integer
            pos = ts.CurrentColumn
            ts.FindPattern(">", vsFindOptions.vsFindOptionsRegularExpression)
            If ts.CurrentColumn = pos Then
                ts.WordRight(False)
                ts.FindPattern(">", vsFindOptions.vsFindOptionsRegularExpression)
            End If
            ts.Insert(tag, EnvDTE.vsInsertFlags.vsInsertFlagsCollapseToStart)
        Else
            ts.MoveToPoint(start)
        End If
    Else
        ts.MoveToPoint(start)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Interesting, but I found this fails when a ) is encountered. I had ).<br/> as the end of line and when I move a <p> tag right, it winds up inside the br element like: <br</p>/>